# Convert a NSInteger to NSString Xcode iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation

I'm trying to convert an NSInteger to a NSString to show the NSInteger value in a UIAlerView. But the problem is that I get this error: "Bad receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long')" when I'm trying to convert the NSInteger.

The NSInteger:

```
NSInteger clasesDadas = clases.count;
```

The clases.count is the number of rows I have in the TableView.

The code is:

```
-(void)infoAction
{
    NSInteger clasesDadas = clases.count;

    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [clasesDadas intValue]]; /*HERE IS THE ERROR*/

    UIAlertView *alertatiempo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Información" message:inStr delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertatiempo show];

}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert NSInteger to NSString datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796390/how-do-i-convert-nsinteger-to-nsstring-datatype)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`intValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/intValue) is not methods that exist on a `NSInteger` but on [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html).
Since [`NSInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html) is a typedef for a primitive type `int` on 32Bit and `long` on 64bit it does not have an methods.

Here is how you'd could do it, casting to make sure it works on both 32 and 64 bit devices.

```
NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)clasesDadas ];
```

---

Also as stated by [meronix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585749/meronix) the count method will result in an `NSUInteger` so you might want to check the type and format accordingly

Comment: Not it is not since the `NSInteger` is signed casting to to unsigned be yield errors. But in a count you better use `NSUInteger `.

Answer (score 7):

You can use with Boxed Expressions.

Eg `@(10).stringValue` or `@(variable).stringValue`

Answer (score 2):

Your clasesDadas is already a `NSInteger`, so you cannot use the method `intValue`.

To convert your integer to string you can convert it in `NSNumber` and use the method `stringValue` like this :

```
NSString *inStr = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:clasesDadas] stringValue]
```

You can also use the syntax `@()` to convert your `NSInteger` to object (NSNumber). For example :

```
NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(clasesDadas)];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)clasesDadas];
```

NSInteger declaration may differ on 32 or 64 bit devices, so this is the apple suggestion to get an array.count for a NSString

Comment: Why are you casting it from signed to unsigned ? In know the count returns a `NSUInteger` but just casting cab yield in unexpected results.

Comment: i was assuming that "count" was NSUInteger, as an array.count, as he said it's "the number of rows I have in the TableView" (NSUInteger)

Comment: yes but then you should also advice to declare  `clasesDadas` as an `NSUInteger`

Comment: right, you changed your comment, as i said: "also", now i agree with you

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", clasesDadas];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)clasesDadas];
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)clases.count];
```