# Trying to create a mutable array with tapped1.view.tag

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create an array with a string using the tag value sent by UITapGestureRecogniser. I keep getting error warnings like cannot convert long __nullable for the following:

```
NSString *tappy = [tapped1.view.tag];
```

Please can someone shed some light on this for me....thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert NSInteger to NSString datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796390/how-do-i-convert-nsinteger-to-nsstring-datatype)

Comment: You can only put objects in a `NS(Mutable)Array`, but do you really have to pass through a `NSString`? You could use a `NSNumber`: `NSNumber *tappy = @(tapped1.view.tag)`, or `NSNumber *tappy = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:tapped1.view.tag];`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *tappy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", tapped1.view.tag]
```

then add this string into your `NSMutableArray`.